# Accessing a row of data in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

For a dataset called combos, the first 6 rows of data is as follows

```
head(combos[,c(1,2,3)])

     Var1   Var2    Var3
1      DD   DD      DD
2       7   DD      DD
3     BBB   DD      DD
4      BB   DD      DD
5       B   DD      DD
6       C   DD      DD
```

I would like to access the values of one row at a time.  The following returns `DD`, as expected.

```
combos[1,1]
```

However, the following returns 1 1 1. What code do I use to get the first row, DD DD DD?

```
c(combos[1,1], combos[1,2], combos[1,3])
```

I need to be able to access the values in a manner like this so I can use a do-for loop with “i” as the row index.   The code is actually from the text ‘Hand-On Programming with R’ by Grolemund and Wickham.  The code above works for them, but something different is happening in my RStudio session or the current version of R.

I have googled and looked, can't figure this one out.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Helena - it looks like your columns are factor variables rather than character variables. Try converting them with `for(i in seq_along(combos)) combos[[i]] <- as.character(combos[[i]])` then repeat your code.

Comment: yes, ugh, that's it!   a rookie mistake; it was driving me nuts.  thank you very much, Allen!